# Inner join with streaming data on Apache Beam/Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I know it is possible to perform inner joins on data on Apache Beam, but I could not find an answer for my specific problem (it is a little more complicated than just joining data).

I am receiving data from two PCollections, which I need to merge. For example:

This is what I receive from PCollection A:

```
{ "key": "key1", "score": ... }
{ "key": "key2", "score": ... }
{ "key": "key3", "score": ... }
...
```

And this is what I receive from PCollection B:

```
{ "id": ..., "key": "key1", "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key1", "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key2", "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "otherScore": ... }
...
```

I would like to join both streams by "key". My output to be this:

```
{ "id": ..., "key": "key1", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key1", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key2", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
{ "id": ..., "key": "key3", "score": ..., "otherScore": ... }
...
```

This is a bit different to your 1-1 join because:

- The entries from PCollection A can be used for several PCollection B. I deally, I would like to store those values for about 4 hours and then drop them. This "caching" is very important.
- The entries from PCollection B can only be used once. They can stay around for about 10 minutes, waiting to be merged, and then can be dropped.

Is this possible to do on Apache Beam? I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you able to add windowing to your pipeline, or are you looking to join two streams without windowing? If you window, then you can just do a `GroupByKey` operation. Otherwise, you'd likely need to rely on state

Comment: I could add a window, but no more than 1h (which goes against the requirement of a 4h cache). Do you think the solution is to leave Dataflow out of this case?

Comment: Why can't you make a greater window than 1h ? A SlidingWindow seems to be appropriate to me

Comment: I am not very familiar with Windowing in Beam. Wouldn't a window end up removing the 'real time' aspect of the pipeline and making it output every X hours?